# Executing shell comamands on remote host in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Why after connection to remote host other commands like docker rm and docker run execute locally, not on remote host. How can I execute commands that written after first command with ssh connection via remote host?

```
                  if (params.Env == 'test') {
                    sshagent (credentials: ['*****-****-****-****-********']) {
                    
                        sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root *.*.*.* uname -a'
                        sh "docker rm mycontainer-'${params.Env}' -f"
                        sh "docker run -d -p 1234:8090 --name mycontainer-'${params.Env}' 10.0.0.1:5050/myproj:'${params.Env}'-'${currentBuild.number}'"
                        
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case should use Credentials Binding plugin for Jenkins - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

For example:

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'ssh_pkey', keyFileVariable: 'identity', passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: 'jenkins')]) {
                
def remote=[:]

remote.name = '$params.Env'

remote.host = 'your_ip_address'

remote.user = 'root'

remote.identityFile=identity

remote.allowAnyHosts = true

sshCommand remote: remote, command: "docker rm container_name -f"

sshCommand remote: remote, command: "docker run -d -p 443:443 --restart always --name 
container_name
```